# PIM contact list inside a LWUIT Tab

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, symbian, nokia-s40

I am new in j2me symbian mobile app development and I am trying to create an sms/chat app with two tabs. Tab1 contains a where the user will choose in a list of contacts and other one contains the new screen for chat. I manage to create a tab using LWUIT and I also have code in accessing the list of contacts as a new midlet. The problem is I don't know how to put it inside the tab as a component. Any suggestion/reference code how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: it's just a question... why you develop in symbian and not in Android or iOS ????

Comment: @Kramnik0 We've already develop it on android. It should be running in all platform. I think, as our client said.